# Let $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $I=[0,1)$, does $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

so I have a problem with 4 convergence questions. I have done the ones where I have to use other methods such as the ratio test and they were OK, but I cannot understand this one in particular.

The problem says: "Let $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $I=[0,1)$, does $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$?"

And the answer says:

The geometric series converges pointwise to $s(x)=\frac{x}{1-x}$.

The sequence of partial sums is $s_n(x)=\frac{x(1-x^{n+1})}{1-x}$ so that
$$s_n(x)-s(x)=\frac{x(1-x^{n+1})}{1-x}-\frac{x}{1-x}=-\frac{x^{n+2}}{1-x}.$$

**And here is where I get it wrong:**

If we take $x=1-1/n$ we get 
$$|s_n(1/n)-f(1/n)|=n(1-1/n)^2(1-1/n)^n$$
which is unbounded since $(1-1/n)^2(1-1/n)^n \to e^{-1}\neq 0$. Therefore, $\sup\limits_{x\in I}|s_n(x)-f(x)|$ does not converge to 0 as $n\to\infty$, so we do not have uniform convergence of the series.

**Comments:**
So I know $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=0$, so when I let x=1-1/n I get
$$|s_n(1-1/n)-f(1-1/n)|=|n(1-1/n)(1-(1-1/n)^{n+1})|=|n(1-1/n-(1-1/n)^2(1-1/n)^n)|$$

And this is very different from the actual result...

I would really appreciate it if you someone could clarify me how this last bit is done. Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite understand. In the section "And here is where I get it wrong", you're using an $x$ that depends on $n$. Of course $s_n(x_n)$ doesn't have to converge to anything if the $x_n$'s depend on $n$.

Comment: There is no problem.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n(1-\frac1n) = \infty$$
As one would expect from
$$\lim_{x\nearrow1} \frac x{1-x} = \infty$$

Comment: Thanks! What I don't understand is why the book says $|s_n(1/n)−f(1/n)|$ instead of $|s_n(1−1/n)−f(1−1/n)|$... :/ I don't see much logic behind it.